# Css input error styling not displaying correctly in Edge browser

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-validate, microsoft-edge

When leaving the fields empty (for testing) and clicking the save button, the input fields should be underlined red with the "Required" text below. I've tested this in IE11, Edge, Chrome and Firefox. It's working as intended except for the Edge browser.

If Test2 field get focus and then you click/tab out, the red underline will show. I've found Test1 is only displayed correctly because the field is focused by jQuery validation. If I had more fields (Test3, Test4, etc.) they would also not be displayed correctly.

Any assistance in figuring out how to get this working in Edge would be greatly appreciated.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9geqo5rm/)

```
<form id="frmTest">
  <div class="md-input-group">
    <input type="text" name="Test" required>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <div class="flex-row helper-row">
      <span class="errorMsg"></span>
    </div>
    <label class="fontL">Test1 Field</label>
  </div>
  <div class="md-input-group">
    <input type="text" name="Test2" required>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <div class="flex-row helper-row">
      <span class="errorMsg"></span>
    </div>
    <label class="fontL">Test2 Field</label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" name="btnSave" id="btnSave">Save</button>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
.md-input-group {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.md-input-group input {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    min-height: 30px;
    padding: 4px 10px 8px 0;
    background: inherit;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38);
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
    outline: none;
}

.md-input-group input:hover {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
}

/* LABEL ======================================= */
.md-input-group > label {
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 18px;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38);
    font-size: 0.938em;
    pointer-events: none;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease all;
       -moz-transition: 0.2s ease all;
            transition: 0.2s ease all;
}

/* LABEL ACTIVE STATE ================================= */
.md-input-group input:focus ~ label, 
.md-input-group input:valid ~ label,
.md-input-group input.error:focus ~ label {
    top: -16px;
    font-size: 0.813em;
    color: rgba(33, 150, 243, 1);
}

/* BOTTOM BARS ================================= */
.md-input-group .bar {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

.md-input-group .bar::before,
.md-input-group .bar::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 2px;
    background: rgba(33, 150, 243, 1);
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease all;
       -moz-transition: 0.2s ease all;
            transition: 0.2s ease all;
}

  .md-input-group .bar::before {
      left: 50%;
  }

  .md-input-group .bar::after {
      right: 50%;
  }

/* BOTTOM BAR ACTIVE STATE ================================= */
.md-input-group input:focus ~ .bar::before,
.md-input-group input:focus ~ .bar::after,
.md-input-group input.error ~ .bar::before,
.md-input-group input.error ~ .bar::after {
    width: 50%;
}

.md-input-group .helper-row {
    justify-content: flex-end;
    min-height: 25px;
}

/* ERROR STATE ================================= */
.md-input-group input.error ~ .bar::before,
.md-input-group input.error ~ .bar::after {
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
}

.md-input-group input.error ~ .helper-row span.errorMsg {
    flex: 1;
    display: block;
    margin: 4px 0;
}

.md-input-group span.errorMsg label {
    color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

jQuery Validate:

```
$('#frmTest').validate({
        rules: {
            Test: {
                required: true,
                maxlength: 10
            },
            Test2: {
                required: true,
                maxlength: 10
            }
        },
        messages: {
            Test: {
                required: "Required",
                maxlength: "Required (max 10 characters)"
            },
            Test2: {
                required: "Required",
                maxlength: "Required (max 10 characters)"
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            $('#btnSave').prop('disabled', true);
            //form.submit();
        },
        highlight: function (element) {
            $(element).addClass('error');
        },
        unhighlight: function (element) {
            $(element).removeClass('error');
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            error.appendTo(element.closest('.md-input-group').find('span.errorMsg'));
        }
    });
```

Comment: You need to put the code into the OP, not solely rely on the Fiddle to see the jQuery Validate code.  Also, tell us if you're testing in the actual browser or within some kind of simulation mode or emulation of Edge.  The only way to reliably test is within the actual browser itself

Comment: @Sparky Updated with jQuery Validate code. Yes, I'm testing in the actual browser(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems due to the different behavior of pseudo classes in Edge. Maybe the different CSS engines used in different browsers caused the issue.

You could change the below code:

```
/* ERROR STATE ================================= */
.md-input-group input.error ~ .bar::before,
.md-input-group input.error ~ .bar::after {
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

into:

```
/* ERROR STATE ================================= */
.md-input-group input.error ~ .bar::before,
.md-input-group input.error ~ .bar {
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
}

.md-input-group input.error ~ .bar::after,
.md-input-group input.error ~ .bar {
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

Then it will be work in Edge.